# Proper way to route url in mvc php?

Tags: php, url, post, model-view-controller, get

What is the proper way to handle this two kind of request:

```
action="probe/test"
test.php?var=value
```

I've tried this:
.htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

php:
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlArray = array();
$urlArray = explode("/",$url);
$controller = $urlArray[1];
array_shift($urlArray);
$action = $urlArray[1];
array_shift($urlArray);
$queryString = $urlArray;
```

But it can be handle only this request:

```
action="probe/test"
```

I have to simply check if url contains "?" and process it diferently?

Comment: This is confusing for the SO users: `action="probe/test"`. Also, why do you need to use both forms of request. Pick one and configurate the web server for it.

Comment: This looks like Apache. I find it easier to simply use `FallbackResource /index.php` instead of all complicated `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: I can see web pages that can handle both kind of url form like this: acion="Controller/Action"
And like this: test.php?variable=value&variable2=value2 how to deal with it?

Comment: What does "handle" or "see" mean exactly? Is `index.php` being invoked at all?